# WordPress: Conditional for Post template Not PAGE

Tags: php, wordpress, conditional-statements, custom-post-type

I have made a custom post template named `single-download.php` after replicating `single.php`. However there are certain customizations which I dont want to show on `single-download.php` but am not able get a specific conditional to achieve the same.

I have tried `if(is_page_template( 'single-download.php' ))` and also `if(!is_page_template( 'single.php' ))` but both don't work.

Is there some way in which we can achieve POST template conditioning? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I finally figured it out. We need to use

`if( !is_singular( 'download' )`

OR

```
if ( is_singular( 'download' ) ) {
// conditional content/code
}
```

It was that simple :)